# Unmet dependencies problem on 12.04 - libcurl4-openssl-dev depends librtmp-dev

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

I'm having troubles with unmet dependencies on Ubuntu 12.04:

`libcurl4-openssl-dev` depends `librtmp-dev`

Here is what I've got after running `sudo apt-get -f install` which suggested running `apt-get autoremove`

The output is identical if I run `sudo apt-get install librtmp-dev`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libmagick++4 libgtkspell0 libgsl0ldbl
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  librtmp-dev
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  librtmp-dev
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 82 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/67.1 kB of archives.
After this operation, 201 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 322166 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking librtmp-dev (from .../librtmp-dev_2.4~20110711.gitc28f1bab-1_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/librtmp-dev_2.4~20110711.gitc28f1bab-1_i386.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/usr/include/librtmp/amf.h', which is also in package rtmpdump 2.5-0ubuntu2~precise
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                          dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/librtmp-dev_2.4~20110711.gitc28f1bab-1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

And here is the result of running `sudo apt-get autoremove`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  libcurl4-openssl-dev : Depends: librtmp-dev but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

This is the output after `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libcurl4-openssl-dev:
 libcurl4-openssl-dev depends on librtmp-dev; however:
  Package librtmp-dev is not installed.
dpkg: error processing libcurl4-openssl-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

The output of `sudo apt-get -u dist-upgrade`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcurl4-openssl-dev : Depends: librtmp-dev but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

The repository source list: `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release i386 (20120423)]/ precise main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main restricted #Added by software-properties

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
deb-src http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise restricted main multiverse universe #Added by software-properties

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted
deb-src http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates restricted main multiverse universe #Added by software-properties

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
deb http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe  multiverse
deb-src http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse #Added by software-properties

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security restricted main multiverse universe #Added by software-properties
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
deb http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/getdeb/ubuntu precise-getdeb apps
deb-src http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/getdeb/ubuntu precise-getdeb apps
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/musicbrainz-developers/stable/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/musicbrainz-developers/stable/ubuntu precise main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/nae-team/ppa/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/nae-team/ppa/ubuntu precise main

deb http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/sonar-pkg/deb binary/
# deb-src http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/sonar-pkg/deb binary/
```

`apt-get clean` and `apt-get autoclean` doesn't do anything to fix this.

And here is the crash report:

[image: package librtmp-dev crash report]

[image: package librtmp-dev crash report 2part]

Help, please!!!

Comment: Here's the problem: `librtmp-dev` is `trying to overwrite '/usr/include/librtmp/amf.h', which is also in package rtmpdump 2.5-0ubuntu2~precise`. Most likely, a PPA is providing this. Run `apt-cache policy rtmpdump` to determine what PPA is giving this package.

Comment: @saiarcot895 Thanks for your answer. What should I do in this case to resolve it?

Comment: @saiarcot895 Here is the result of `apt-cache policy rtmpdump`
rtmpdump:
  `Installed: 2.5-0ubuntu2~precise`
  `Candidate: 2.5-0ubuntu2~precise`
  `Version table:`
 `*** 2.5-0ubuntu2~precise 0`
        `100 /var/lib/dpkg/status`
     `2.4~20110711.gitc28f1bab-1 0`
        `500 http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/universe i386 Packages`

Comment: Ok, so you installed it from somewhere, but then removed the link to that repo. Run `sudo dpkg --remove rtmpdump`. If that completes successfully, run `sudo dpkg --configure -a`.

Comment: @saiarcot895 run `sudo dpkg --remove rtmpdump` - that didn't yield any errors, then run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` but it complained that librtmp-dev is not installed, so I install it with `apt-get install librtmp-dev` and that went smooth and then run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` which didn't yield anything. So I guess that was the end of my problems with package dependencies. Thank you a lot. Please make your comment an answer so I'll be able to accept it and upvote it. Thank you again!!! P.S. Update Manager start working again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `librtmp-dev` is `trying to overwrite '/usr/include/librtmp/amf.h', which is also in package rtmpdump 2.5-0ubuntu2~precise`. Most likely, a PPA or some other repo is providing this package, as the version in the main repos is `2.4~20110711.gitc28f1bab-1`.

The solution is to remove `rtmpdump` by running `sudo dpkg --remove rtmpdump`, and then to run `sudo apt-get install librtmp-dev` to have `apt` install the correct package and configure all needed packages.