# Cannot seem to install libcurl4-openssl-dev package

Tags: 14.04, apt, 64-bit, libraries

I am unable to install this package. This is what I get when I used apt-get to install it. Running 14.04 64bit.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libcurl4-openssl-dev : Depends: librtmp-dev but it is not going to be installed 
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

And the output of `apt-cache policy libcurl4-openssl-dev librtmp-dev`

```
libcurl4-openssl-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 7.35.0-1ubuntu2.5
  Version table:
     7.35.0-1ubuntu2.5 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
     7.35.0-1ubuntu2 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
librtmp-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.4+20121230.gitdf6c518-1
  Version table:
     2.4+20121230.gitdf6c518-1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Add the output of `apt-cache policy libcurl4-openssl-dev librtmp-dev` to your question, please. ([Edit] it, don't post command outputs as comment).

Comment: I have done so.

Comment: Please also add the output of `apt-mark showhold`, if there is any, and run `sudo apt-get install -f` and add this output too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It simply means that there are some other packages which need to be installed before you can install the package you want to. This is called a dependency in Linux world.

There are a few ways to resolve this:

- One possible cause of unmet dependencies could be corrupted package database, and/or some packages weren’t installed properly. To fix this problem, hit Alt+Ctrl+T to open terminal and try to run one of the following commands:
  `sudo apt-get clean`
  or
  `sudo apt-get autoclean`
  Autoclean clears out the local repository of downloaded packages which are no longer required.
- Or you can try getting the dependencies resolved through apt-get
  `sudo apt-get -f install`
  The `-f` switch tries to correct the broken dependencies.

**For a more comprehensive guide, refer to https://askubuntu.com/a/142808/456878

And keep it handy for reference.**

Comment: @Eric Seagal Another common issue with the aforementioned package is that it sometimes tries to overwrite a few files of the rtmpdump package. See [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/509084/456878) too.